# JTextField isn't appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I want JTextField to appear on the center on the panel using borderlayout but it isn't appearing, buttons appear but JTextField doesn't..

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class cal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField answer= new JTextField("0");
        panel.add(answer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Call `frame.setVisible(true);` only once all components have been added .

Comment: What buttons? You have no buttons here... You should also `pack` the Frame

Answer (score 0):

You must call setVisible(true) on your frame after adding components.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class cal {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField answer = new JTextField("0");
        panel.add(answer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Explain what the changes are and why you made the changes. Comparing code doesn't help with understanding why you made the changes.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.